# x64 assembly functions (call/return vs push/pop/jump)

Tags: function, assembly, 64-bit, x86-64

Whats the difference between using the built-in call and return instructions vs manually pushing and popping the stack and using jumps for functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functionally, if you do it correctly, nothing.
However it takes more instructions and/or registers to emulate `call`/`ret` using `push`/`pop`. Of course if you really wanted to take it to the extreme, you could also emulate `push`/`pop` using `lea` and `mov` :)

Also, current processors have specialized hardware to handle function calls for the purposes of branch prediction, which probably won't work for your alternate sequence so you will get performance penalty.